# server-sent-events: How to trigger sending

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I read this about server sent events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events There they give an example in PHP for sending an event. I've learned that the header instruction must be the very first instruction in a script. However I need to do some preprocessing before sending the event:

```
//Do some preprocessing in order the determine whether to send an event or not
if ($sendevent) {
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
    // echo the data
}
```

Obviously this is not possible as "header" is not the first instruction. How to solve this problem? Can sending an event only be triggered by sending a request from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation for the `header()` function says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent.

It means you can include any number of instructions but your script must not output anything before calling `header()`.
Your `if` doesn't output anything, so it's fine.

Be careful not to have whitespace characters before the PHP opening tag.

Comment: I see! This was a misunderstanding  on my side: The requirement only applies to data transmitted to the client, not to PHP code in the script not being delivered to the client. Many thanks for this information!